# How to eliminate Security Warning message on EC2 Instance wizard

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, ip-address

I've set up the AWS Free Tier, and configured a Windows Server.  I took the defaults pretty much.  There was 1 security group it created with 3 security rules it provided by default, and I didn't change anything.  It looks like it added SQL Server's default TCP port of 1433, and IIS default web site port of 80, and Windows RDP port for remote desktop.  I don't know what the IP addresses will be since I read that EC2 automatically assigns a public and private IP address per instance.

Why is it complaining about the security when the rules don't even have specific IP addresses?  How can I fix this?

> Improve your instances' security. Your security group,
>   launch-wizard-1, is open to the world. Your instances may be
>   accessible from any IP address. We recommend that you update your
>   security group rules to allow access from known IP addresses only. You
>   can also open additional ports in your security group to facilitate
>   access to the application or service you're running, e.g., HTTP (80)
>   for web servers.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess 0.0.0.0/0 meant I opened the port up to the world for each port forwarded.  I just edited security and chose "My IP" for each rule.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this. For example, I do want to have port 80 open to the world right? Does it mean that I can't eliminate the warning message?